# Change Alpha of a UIImage Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, splash-screen

I'm still exploring xCode/Objective-C, And I was wondering how would I be able to change the alpha of a UIImage. I tried writing my own code but I get the error 'Property 'alpha' not found on object of type UIImage'. The splash screen works if I comment out the alpha changing lines. My code is below.

```
//
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImage *logo;

@end

@implementation ViewController

ADBannerView *_bannerView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(showLogo:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void)showLogo:(NSTimer *) timer{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    self.logo.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        self.logo.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        ViewController *controller  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }];

}];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

//Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the alpha of the `UIImageView` it is contained in, there is no alpha property for `UIImage`.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is shown by @JMarsh

I have found method that change the alpha value. you can try this.

```
imageView.image=[self imageByApplyingAlpha:image]
```

//Change alpha of image

```
   - (UIImage *)imageByApplyingAlpha:(CGFloat) alpha {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0.0f);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, alpha);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, self.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: This is changing orientation.